# ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool unkown Error ASP.NET 4 VS 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, asp.net-4.0

I was following the [MVCMusic](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/) tutorial with an machine with full sql server 2008 r2
and full visual studio professional, in ***ASP.NET 4.0*** and when I got to the page where it sets up membership (near page 66) the Web administration tool wont work, i got the following error:

An error was encountered. Please return to the previous page and try again.

my web config is like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <clear />
        <add name="MvcMusicStoreCN" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MvcMusicStore;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="MvcMusicStoreEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Store.csdl|res://*/Models.Store.ssdl|res://*/Models.Store.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MvcMusicStore;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

<system.web>
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
                     connectionStringName="MvcMusicStoreCN" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
                     enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
                     maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
                     passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" passwordFormat="Hashed"  />
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile>
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" 
                     connectionStringName="MvcMusicStoreCN" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add connectionStringName="MvcMusicStoreCN" applicationName="/"
                  name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
                <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"
                  type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <customErrors mode="Off">
        </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

EDIT: I've run the

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regsql.exe
```

executable and added the tables to my MvcMusicStore database sucessfully, changed the web.config from ***MY*** application (MVCMusicStore), and tryed running the ASP.NET Configuration shortcut, and got the error.
My Default Browser is firefox, and when I click the shortcut the browser doesn't even open the page, only when I right click on the tray icon and choose open in web browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved it, I entered another project (VS 2010 doesn't let me change the default browser in an MVC project) changed the default browser, changed back to the MVC project and tryed opening the configuration again, and it worked.
Looks like the configuration doesn't allow firefox.
Thanks Anyway Raj.

Answer (score 0):

Get your app to show detailed errors by turning off custom errors
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(VS.71).aspx

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off">
      </customErrors>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It didn't change i've put this on my local web.config and on the WAT physical directory.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\asp.netwebadminfiles\

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this problem and found out it was because the directory my solution was in contained a weird character. 'C:....\C#'   Changing the directory to CSharp got rid of this problem.