# ASP.NET MVC Configuration Manager error

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, authorization

The WSAT throws the following irrespective of the project or the connection type,

> An error was encountered. Please
>   return to the previous page and try
>   again.

Even on a brand new ASP.NET MVC 2 website where user authentication and registration work through the default account controller without a quibble, the WSAT fails to run.

Things I've tried,

- [Tried to open it in IE.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917694/asp-net-web-site-administration-tool-unkown-error-asp-net-4-vs-2010)
- [Tried to use it with MySQL to setup
  user authorization, role and profile
  management. *This was the goal which
  is starting to seem more and more
  like an uphill battle.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512852/how-do-i-setup-asp-net-mvc-2-with-mysql)
- Tried it    with a brand new ASP.NET
  MVC 2    application.

Help would be **greatly** appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Apparently the configuration manager will not work if the directory path to the solution contains invalid characters, in my case it was a space.

Should be documented somewhere, this was a good waste of four hours..